# C++1z(?) runtime sized array as a return value

Tags: c++, c++14, variable-length-array

Can we not do anything like this?

```
auto f(int n, char *arr[]) -> decltype(char *[n]) /* doesn't work */ {
    char *tmp[n]; // RSA, the size depends on argc
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) tmp[i] = arr[i];
    return tmp;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    auto arr = f(argc, argv);
    for (auto e : arr)
        cout << e << endl;
}
```

I love value semantics (as long as my compiler can do proper inlining) especially when I refactor a large function into a set of smaller utilities.

Edit: oops, it didn't make it into C++14... (Changed the title from "C++14" to "C++1z(?)".)  How about "Array Extensions TS"?  Does it support anything like this?

Comment: C++14 doesn't have runtime sized arrays. There are implementations of `string_view` and `array_view` that you could use to wrap the parameters, but those aren't standard yet either.

Comment: Built-in arrays have been abandoned by new C++ language development because they suck. You must either use `std::array` or `std::vector` or similar to take advantage of such wonderful features as returning an array.

Answer (score 3):

The canonical C++ way to do what you want to do is to use a `std::vector` (or `std::array` if the number of elements is known at compile time). C++ does not use VLAs, as noted in M.M's answer.

If the character pointers involved are not going to be dangling (e.g., in your `argv` case), you can do this:

```
std::vector<char*> f(int n, char** arr)
{
    std::vector<char*> tmp;
    tmp.reserve(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        tmp.push_back(arr[i]);
    return tmp;
}
```

If the pointers will dangle, it's better to create `std::string` objects:

```
std::vector<std::string> f(int n, char** arr)
{
    std::vector<std::string> tmp;
    tmp.reserve(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        tmp.emplace_back(arr[i]);
    return tmp;
}
```

(`emplace_back` is new to C++11. In older C++ versions, you can just use `push_back`.)

Comment: `vector<char *>` would be more akin to OP's code, which doesn't copy the string contents. (Unclear which version suits his needs better of course)

Comment: @M.M My original answer did use `vector<char*>`, but I didn't want to risk any danglingness, so.... (Granted, a non-problem for `argv`, but in general.)

Comment: Even in C, which has VLAs, you cannot return arrays from functions (and in particular you cannot return VLAs).

Comment: `char*` vs `string` or whatever is irrelevant to the main topic.  In fact my real use case has nothing to do with `argc` / `argv`.

Comment: @nodakai Great! Then just use the appropriate `vector` type and go from there. It's the common way to do variable-sized-array-like things in C++.

Answer (score 2):

VLAs are not permitted in any version of ISO C++ .

Some compilers offer VLA as an extension. You will need to consult the documentation for your compiler to see details about the nature of the extension.

It seems unlikely to me that returning a VLA would be allowed by any extension (or by C++17 if VLAs make it in), since returning an array (even a non-VLA) does not make sense.

There is no syntax that specifies returning an array by value; in the line `return tmp;`, `tmp` decays to a pointer.  Arrays do not have value semantics.

Comment: Tagging your compiler might help, although posting on mailing list for your compiler might be the best option to get a definitive answer about whether the compiler allows returning a VLA